# Authorization header is not sent in API request

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 8 and react for frontend. I'm using laravel passport for authentication.

Once user logs in, a token is generated and stored in browser's local storage. Then after retriving access token from local storage I setting it into the axios `Authorization` header to verify the user authenticity on every request.

I am integrating Paytm payment gateway using standard checkout.

I have created a callback API which call after transaction is completed and this API is  protected by `auth:api` middleware means only logged in users can access the API.

So when user click on pay button, he is redirected to Paytm payment gateway page. On this page user does not have the access token in local storage.

So once transaction is completed callback API is called but no token is sent in the request `Authorization` header and user is restricted to access the API.

I have even tried saving access token in session before user redirects to payment gateway page and retrieves it in the middleware attached on the callback API but session value is `null`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Remove the `auth:api` middleware from this resource(route) by `->withoutMiddleware('auth:api')` to let the other service be able to utilize you resource.

Comment: `aurh:api` middleware helps to verify whether user is logged or not. I want only logged in users to access this API. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can generate a key for every payment every time a user came to buy by to be loaded on query parameters when the other service came to talk to you will be able to know who's the user for paid this.


Another approach, When you talk to your payment service to create a payment they send you at least a transaction id or unique id for this process and the same when they are trying to notify you with the response of the process of payment.

The two approaches you should remove the `auth:api` middleware.